# java Random String With Exclusion

Tags: java, android, string, random

i create  this method in java to get a random string:

```
public String getRandomStringWithExclusion(int array_id, String... exclude) {

    String[] myResArray = getResources().getStringArray(array_id);
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(myResArray.length);
    String random = (myResArray[idx]);

    for (String ex : exclude) {
        if (random.contains(ex)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fail", Utils.duration).show();
            break;
        }

    }

    return random;
}
```

but when i call:
    getRandomStringWithExclusion(R.array.test,
                        "test a");  it returns the excluded value.
how can you fix?

I'm no expert of java. I'm beginner. thanks in

Comment: Hi, do you mean random = "test a" at the end? Isn't it making sense as you are not modifying  random anywhere and so if it was set to be an exclude value in the first place, then it will remain as is?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to return a random value from `myResArray` but can't be contained within the Array of `exclude` right?

Comment: It's hard to tell what are you trying to achieve just by the example code. One sure thing is, `random` value is being returned unaffected from the method despite contains check.

Comment: instead of break i put getRandomStringWithExclusion(array_id, exclude)  ??    @gtgaxiola yes right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it but surely is not the most optimized:

The gist is that if your `random` String is contained withing `exclude`, then you HAVE to select another `random` and restart the check.

```
public String getRandomStringWithExclusion(int array_id, String... exclude) {
    String[] myResArray = getResources().getStringArray(array_id);
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(myResArray.length);
    String random = (myResArray[idx]);
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while (keepGoing) {
        //Making keepGoing be false (terminating condition),
        //And only making true if the random word fails because it has to be excluded
        keepGoing = false;
        for (String ex : exclude) {
            if (random.contains(ex)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fail", Utils.duration).show();
                keepGoing = true;
                //looking for another random word
                idx = new Random().nextInt(myResArray.length);
                random = (myResArray[idx]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return random;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you still got your toast message, do you?
So your code works fine.

You did not react on the returning behaviour if you found it (means: no matter if you find sth, you will retrun it).
instead of break use:

```
return "";
```

This will stop searching for more restrictions and return the method with nothing as result.

Greetings.

Comment: i need a value. not a "" result

Comment: Sorry, did not take that point,
just try to use recursive on this point.
'return getRandomStringWithExclusion(array_id, exclude)' should be working fine, instead of 'return ""'